# Restricting API Calls to a Certain Domain

Tags: angularjs, api, rest, facebook-graph-api, fuelphp

My app uses JS Facebook API to use Facebook as a login/pass. Here what happens when you try to login.

1. User click on the Facebook Login Button
2. Facebook Authenticates
3. If Success. I grab the Facebook ID and Name of the user
4. Calls on my REST API on my APP to check and see if the that FBID is registered in my system.
5. If Registered, I write the session to verify that the user is authenticated.

This is great since I don't have to store usernames and password. But I am worried that someone will just use a REST API debugger like POSTMAN in chrome and just send a Facebook ID and the name of the user and they will be authenticated.

My question is what is the best way to secure my end that will prevent apps like POSTMAN to just input the fields needed to authenticate? Am I missing something? Can anyone recommend a strategy for this?

Or is using CSRF token the only way to combat this? I am using FuelPHP as a backend and doing a single page app using AngularJS with NgRoutes. But every time I enabled the CSRF on fuel, the token passed does not match what it was in the back-end.

I am under the impression that this is due to that the javascript token function is in the main page, where the ng-view. I know this might have something to do with the ngRoutes.

http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/security.html

Comment: store user in your db but have an extra field in db for `provider` like "facebook" or "myApp" or "twitter" etc. The outside providers send you back some user data when user initially accepts connecting to your app

Comment: @charlietfl for example like in FB, should I also store the access_token and secret it gives out when the user authenticates?

Comment: To be honest...I haven't set one up for a while and don't remember the specifics of the returned data when user agrees. I would have to look through the docs. But you can always assign a token to that user also

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests

Answer (score 0):

Use Fuel's Auth package. It has Opauth integration which does all the above, and for an entire list of social media platforms, not only facebook.

Always try not to reinvent the wheel, assume someone else has had the same challenge, solved at, and shared the solution with the community.